# c# DateTime convert error - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I keep getting an error when trying to convert a string into a DateTime.

```
Error:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

The string I'm trying to convert is gotten from a DataTable. Odd thing is, if I use just the date by itself and put it in a string, there's no error. The error only comes up when I get the date from the table.

This is the date that is giving my trouble: 2008-04-20T07:00:00Z

Here is my code:

```
string dateString = "2008-04-20T07:00:00Z";

foreach (DataRow dr in tblData.Rows)
{
        string tblDate = dr["DOCUMENTDATE"].ToString();
        string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";

        DateTime convertDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tblDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        //DateTime convertDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        dr["DOCUMENTDATE"] = convertDate.ToString();
    }
```

I've looked up other posts and tried Parse, ParseExact, Convert.ToDateTime and still get the same error.

**EDIT 1:**

The data type for dr["DOCUMENTDATE"] is a string.
The data filling the table is gotten from a json that is converted into xml. I then used XMLtoDataTable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you look at tblDate in the debugger. The obvious conclusion is that it doesnt contain what you think it contains

Comment: try to show your sample data here from your table.

Comment: I checked that as well. The output from tblDate DOCUMENTDATE is the correct value (i.e. 2008-04-20T07:00:00Z)

Comment: Yeah i agree no database accept that value if you have a datetime data type unless he make it a varchar..

Comment: it is not a valid datetime value exactly.

Comment: Check if 'tblDate' contains any trailing white spaces. In that case, you can use 'DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite'

Comment: Reds, can you explain that a little bit more? Sorry I'm still a novice.

Comment: @trooperEOF you are just forcing to find a needle in a wide desert place.

Comment: @RK_Aus no trailing white space.

Comment: What type is `dr["DOCUMENTDATE"]`  in the first place? **S**eperation **o**f **C**oncerns should be followed and if a value is representing a date and/or time it should be saved with the propert type: `DateTime`. How it's seen in the UI is a presentation layer concern, so do your formatting there into 8601 or whatever variant that is needed at view time

Comment: Just to second @RK_AUS' point, I'd look at the result of `tblDate.ToCharArray()` in the debugger and double-check that there are no unexpected whitespace/unprintable characters that may not be otherwise evident. `ParseExact` will throw that exception if passed a string containing whitespace it's not instructed to allow (via `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces` and similar values). You may even go so far as to check the ASCII values and make sure all of the characters really are what you think they are (e.g. Is that hyphen really a hyphen or an [en dash](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash)?).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. @MadMyche, I just checked and the type for dr["DOCUMENTDATE"] is System.String.

Comment: Further notes: The data that fills the DataTable was gotten from a json which was converted into xml so I could use XMLtoDataTable

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this, have you made sure there are no extra spaces in there. like before or after. Use tblDate.Trim() instead and see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this. I think the problem is that you're not providing a recognizable format:

Relevant fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u1IoNX

```
    string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
    string tblDate = dr["DOCUMENTDATE"].ToString(format);


    DateTime convertDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tblDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    dr["DOCUMENTDATE"] = convertDate.ToString(format);
```

**EDIT**

From the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx

> The DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)
>   method parses the string representation of a date, which must be in a
>   format defined by the format parameter.

If I use your datestring example above, I do not get any errors. Your date may look correct in the debugger, but I do not believe that it is formatting exactly as it should to match your specified format.

Comment: the problem here is he just trying to convert that sample string into datetime.

Comment: it's very likely that the dr["DOCUMENTDATE"] is not in the same format as the test value dateString = "2008-04-20T07:00:00Z"

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It doesn't allow the "format" argument for ToString().